# При команде createsuperuser Django выдает ошибку

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Я сделал сайт на Django REST API и начал деплоить на VPS и у меня сначала была ошибка о кодировки `LATIN-1` при команде `python manage.py migrate` исправил изменив кодировку таблицы с `LATIN-1` на `UTF-8` и миграция прошла успешна без ошибок

Но потом при команде `python manage.py createsuperuser` выдала ошибку

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(256)`

Из-за чего мб эта ситуация

Я попробовал многое
База данных на PostgreSQL
OC Ubuntu 20.04amd64-fromdisk
Python 3.8

Comment: Проверьте [настройки локали](https://sysadminium.ru/regional-settings-locale-in-linux/) в системе и убедитесь, что по умолчанию используется локаль с кодировкой UTF-8 (на некоторых VPS это по умолчанию почему-то не так)

Comment: И если вдруг окажется не UTF-8, то после изменения локали перезагрузите VPS

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать:

```
ALTER TABLE <имя> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONVERT"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE admin CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8...

Comment: Ага. Значит это для Postgres неприменимо. Я делал так в MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Описание моделей в файле models.py, скорее всего в названии одной из моделей, или в одном из полей модели присутствует кириллица. Точно не уверен, почему именно на сервере такое происходить, возможно конфликт в связке Gunicorn + Django + nginx. Что касается createsuperuser, возможно автор где-то переопределил стандартное поведение модели и допустил наличие кириллицы.

Comment: Ответ непонятен. В каком конкретно описании? Как именно кириллица приводит к появлению этой ошибки? Почему именно во время createsuperuser, а не во время migrate или makemigrations?

Comment: Описание моделей в файле models.py, скорее всего в названии одной из моделей, или в одном из полей модели присутствует кириллица. Точно не уверен, почему именно на сервере такое происходить, возможно конфликт в связке Gunicorn + Django + nginx. Что касается createsuperuser, возможно автор где-то переопределил стандартное поведение модели и допустил наличие кириллицы.

Comment: @user510170 это нужно дописать в сам ответ. Сейчас у вас ответ больше похож на комментарий, а комментарий - больше на ответ. Вся максимально полная информация должна быть в самом ответе.

Comment: Какое-то гадание на кофейной гуще, а не ответ

Comment: Ну, по сути так и есть. Автор не предоставил код для анализа. А так, в случае этой ошибки я указал направление для поиска решения.